# Vowels in the pronunciation of the word literally

Tags: word-usage, pronunciation

According to the [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/literally),I have three questions about the pronunciation of the word "literally":

1. according to the voice on the web,as if the first vowel letter i in UK English is pronounced as a long vowel /i/,is it right?
2. /ˈlɪt̬·ər·ə·li/,the second vowel is weakened.So in US English it is pronounced as a non-retro-flex,and in UK English it will be ignored?
3. why the second is weakened,not the third one?How is the rule?

Answer (score 1):

1. You're mistaken; the vowel is short, both phonologically and phonetically. It is the /ɪ/ vowel found in words such as *lit, sit, kit.* I don't know what voice you're referring to; if you mean the recorded pronunciations on the Cambridge dictionary site, you've misheard the vowel. They do both use the /ɪ/ phoneme.
2. The vowel being weakened does not mean it would not be pronounced with r-coloring/retroflexion in American English. If anything, the reverse is probably true: "weakened" or reduced vowel are more likely to assimilate to adjacent sounds. In fact, some analyses treat a schwa followed by "r" as a syllabic consonant /r̩/ with no vowel at all.

   It's true that the first schwa is likely to be dropped in UK English, resulting in a pronunciation with three syllables, /lɪtrəli/. This seems to be due to the stress pattern of the word, but it's complicated to explain the exact conditions and I'm not sure I can do it. If you're really interested in learning this, there's a [post I made on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/308642/77227) that has some information I found that might be helpful from "[Optimality Theory and Prosody](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~hammond/thursday.html)", by Michael Hammond. An example word he gives that shows the same pattern of schwa loss is *respiratory* > *resp'ratory.*
3. The third vowel is a schwa, and therefore I would say it is a "weak" or reduced vowel. It just isn't dropped, probably for stress-related reasons as I said above.